# how to execute dialing a queue in twilio php?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

How do I execute this code?

```
$response = new Twiml();
$dial = $response->dial();
$dial->queue('support', ['url' => 'about_to_connect.xml']);

echo $response;
```

I'm using laravel and used this function on button click. All I get is a Twiml return.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Let me explain the use of [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) within Twilio applications. TwiML does not initiate phone calls, it is used to react to events within phone calls.

When you [receive an incoming call to your Twilio number](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml) or when you [make a call via the Voice API which connects](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/make-calls), Twilio then needs to ask your application what to do with that call. It does so by making an HTTP request to the URL you provide for the phone number or via the API request. Your application needs to respond to that request with TwiML to provide the instructions for the call.

In your case, it looks like you're trying to make a call to a number and then connect that user to the first person waiting in the support queue. To do that, you should keep the TwiML you have, just don't execute it on the button click.

Instead, when your user clicks the button you should make the API call to generate the call and direct Twilio to call this TwiML when the call connects.

This [tutorial on click to call using Twilio and Laravel](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/click-to-call-php-laravel) should help with this.